# Qual a lógica para descobrir todas os possíveis números que somados da o número solicitado?

Tags: lógica

Mas note que o número da esquerda é sempre maior que o da direita. Já tentei de diversas formas, mas acho que não entendi a lógica para criar um algoritmo que faça isso por isso falho sempre em números maiores que 8.

Exemplo: 8 decomposto ficaria
8
7 + 1
6 + 2
6 + 1 + 1
5 + 3
5 + 2 + 1
5 + 1 + 1 + 1
4 + 4
4 + 3 + 1
4 + 2 + 2
4 + 2 + 1 + 1
4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
3 + 3 + 2
3 + 2 + 2 + 1
3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Comment: Essa página é destinada a problemas específicos de programação. De uma olhada no [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @AugustoVasques ao meu ver esse é um problema específico de programação e é válido no site.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e Turista sugestão para analisarem: [Find all possible subsets that sum up to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331308/1518921), dos que encontrei me pareceu o mais simples de entender e talvez até mais eficiente que os demais, não fiz um benchmark ainda, mas nem é esta a necessidade aqui, quando sobrar um tempo irei tentar postar os resultados dos testes de performance.

Answer (score 1):

Tratam-se de partições numéricas. Uma solução possível é encontrar as combinações e remover duplicados.

```
def sum_to_n(n):
    b, mid, e = [0], list(range(1, n)), [n]
    splits = [d for i in range(n) for d in combinations(mid, i)]
    list1 = [map(sub, chain(s, e), chain(b, s)) for s in splits]
    return set([tuple(sorted(t, reverse=True)) for t in list1])
```